# User-friendly wrappings for tail recursive functions

Tags: recursion, lisp, sbcl

I am trying to learn common lisp. I'm familiar with tail recursion, but I'm unfamiliar with the idiomatic way to wrap a tail recursive function in a way that the caller does not have to initialize the accumulator variable(s). Here is an example:

```
(defun add-em (n s) 
    (if (eql n 0) 
        s 
        (add-em (- n 1) (+ s n))
    )
)
```

Say I wanted to wrap this function so that the user only has to manage inputting `n` and does not need the full function call `(add-em <number> 0)`. In other languages, such as scala, I would define an inner function and then at the end of the outer function I would call the tail-recursive inner function to run the algorithm.

In common lisp I could define a lambda in the function and use that, but it seems kind of ugly. I figured there may be a more idiomatic way to do it but googling hasn't really given me any results.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this other than splitting the functions entirely? Or is that the best way? An example:

```
(defun add-em-inner (num sum)
       (if (eql num 0)
       sum
       (add-em-inner (- num 1) (+ num sum))
       )
)

(defun add-em (n) 
  (add-em-inner n 0)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `labels` operator to define a lexical function that is recursive. So that is to say:

```
(defun add-em-inner (num sum)
       (if (eql num 0)
           sum
           (add-em-inner (- num 1) (+ num sum))))

(defun add-em (n) 
  (add-em-inner n 0))
```

Becomes this:

```
(defun add-em (n) 
  (labels ((add-em-inner (num sum)
             (if (eql num 0)
               sum
               (add-em-inner (- num 1) (+ num sum)))))
    (add-em-inner n 0)))
```

If you don't mind the extra accumulator being part of the function's public interface, but care only about user  convenience (caller not having to specify the value), you can just make it an optional parameter:

```
(defun add-em (n &optional (s 0)) 
    (if (eql n 0) 
        s 
        (add-em (- n 1) (+ s n))))
```

There are often good reasons not to do that; for instance, you may want to retain the ability to define an optional argument for future API extension that is backwards compatible. That is still possible here, but only provided that the outside callers don't pass that parameter.

Comment: With an local function, you can also check types only once, like `n` here which should be non-negative.

Comment: The `optional` approach also allows the user to specify a non-default accumulator when they would like to. For example, summing a list of lists of numbers could be done by passing the total of all previous lists as the initial accumulator for the next list. Users get to ignore `s` when they're not interested - or specify it when they are - win win.